# How do you reinstall wine after upgrading?

Tags: upgrade, 13.04, wine

I upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 13.04. After doing this, I get this error when trying to reinstall wine:E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing? How do you fix a missing archive? My current interest in wine is some windows MIDI software. I have a MIDI uno. It was working before the upgrade but now I am having some trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into settings, software and updates.

Go into the other tab and make sure the appropriate repositories are enabled.

Comment: Ok I think I might know what the problem is. I did as you said (thanks) but was still unable to solve the problem. I think the problem is I have added several of the same link http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu raring (main) (Source Code) So how how do you remove the extra ones? The remove button is grayed out.

Comment: You can also get to them by path:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d

But they are grey on mine until I highlight with left click, then I can remove them once I click one in the list.

Comment: No problem.  Can you mark the answer as having answered the issue please?  This lets everyone know the question is answered and deals out rep points etc...

Comment: I am brand new and just reinstalled the system all over again and it got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

> `sudo apt upgrade`

and **not** `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

This actually fixed my issue. Very simple but worked

Comment: Hello. This isn't the issue, since these command does exactly the same thing - I promise you.